# delete obsolete archivelog

Tags: oracle, amazon-rds, aws, rman

I have an oracle instance aws recently migrated to RDS aws
I just noticed that my database is set by default in archivelog mode and that the archivelog are not deleted
who has any idea how deleted the obsolete archivelog in RDS
how to run rman command in RDS AWS ?

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for AWS, but for a normal, on-premesis database, one would normally do archivelog housekeeping during the normal rman backup process:

```
rman> backup archivelog all delete all input;
```